# I have gone through one Vba code, i want to know the meaning what will it do

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function CheckKeywordAndReplace(ByVal searchKeyword As String, ByVal replaceKeyword As String, ByVal k As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim isFound As Boolean

    isFound = False

     If Sheets(3).Range("AX" & k) = Empty Then
        Set rgFound = Sheets(3).Range("AE" & k).Find(searchKeyword, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rgFound Is Nothing Then
            Sheets(3).Range("AX" & k).Value = replaceKeyword
            isFound = True
        End If
    End If

    CheckKeywordAndReplace = isFound

End Function
```

Comment: You need to be more precise about **which** part exactly of the code did you not understand? Otherwise the question is too broad to answer. Actually there is no question, you didn't ask one. • And tell what you already understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly needs to be explained so I added comments above each line of code.

This function searches for string `searchKeyword` in `Sheets(3)` (third sheet in the workbook) in column "AK", where row is argument `k`.

For example, if `k` is `1`:
If `AX1` is empty and `AE1` consists of `searchKeyword`, it will populate `AX1` with `replaceKeyword`. It will find word "us" in "ho**us**e" if that's intended.

Function returns `Boolean` data type which is either `True` or `False` - it returns `True` when `AX` was populated.

```
Function CheckKeywordAndReplace(ByVal searchKeyword As String, ByVal replaceKeyword As String, ByVal k As Integer) As Boolean

    'declare data type (boolean is only True or False)
    Dim isFound As Boolean

    'this is not needed as default boolean is False
    isFound = False

    'if range is empty
    If Sheets(3).Range("AX" & k) = Empty Then
       'search for your keyword
       Set rgFound = Sheets(3).Range("AE" & k).Find(searchKeyword, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
       'if keyword found
       If Not rgFound Is Nothing Then
           'replace value with your keyword
           Sheets(3).Range("AX" & k).Value = replaceKeyword
           'update result from False to True
           isFound = True
       End If
    End If

    'return result boolean - this will be True if keyword was found and replaced
    CheckKeywordAndReplace = isFound

End Function
```

This function could be improved. For a start, the `IsFound` is not needed as function itself returns `Boolean` which is `False` by default. You didn't declare all data types, this is not a mistake by all means, just something to point out; I advise you to use [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement). Also I suggest setting the worksheet object, especially if you have multiple workbooks open. Instead of `.Find` you can use `InStr` function, nothing wrong with it it's just a different way of doing the same thing. You can also use `Like` operator with wildcards but it's not supported in VBScript so personally I tend not to use it. Here's my approach:

```
Option Explicit
Function CheckKeywordAndReplace(ByVal searchKeyword As String, ByVal replaceKeyword As String, ByVal k As Integer) As Boolean

    'declare data types
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng_search As Range

    'set objects
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3) 'third sheet in the workbook where the macro is stored
    Set rng_search = ws.Range("AX" & k)

    'if range value is empty
    If rng_search.Value = vbNullString Then
       'if value has searchKeyword
       If InStr(ws.Range("AE" & k).Value, searchKeyword) > 0 Then
       'alternatively you can use Like operator, it's commented out
       'If ws.Range("AE" & k).Value Like "*" & searchKeyword & "*" Then
           'replace value with your keyword
           rng_search.Value = replaceKeyword
           'update result from False to True
           CheckKeywordAndReplace = True
       End If
    End If

End Function
```